# Which maven archetype to use?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I'm developing a distributed application which uses **Spring, Hibernate, RMI** framework. I'm using **Eclipse** and **m2eclipse** plugin for development.

I was creating **New Maven Project** but when browsing through available **archetype** catalog, I got confused which archetype to use. My questions are

- What choices do I have?
- Which one is the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use the maven-archetype-webapp one. It's simple and won't have anything you don't want. I've tried using the archetypes that already include Spring, but inevitably something isn't set up how I want it, and it's easier to add spring yourself than modify a pre-existing Spring set-up to be how you want it.

I also think it's best to add the hibernate dependencies yourself.

For adding those dependencies, though, this [tutorial](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/04/06/migrating-to-spring-3-1-and-hibernate-4-1/) is very helpful. Make sure to check out the GitHub project and look at it!